# SQL Query - Exists in other table or does not

Tags: sql

Apologies for the somewhat confusing title. It's difficult to summarise the issue in a couple of words. I am making a request to a database, on the following tables:

`Event`:

```
ID, startdate, offtime, meetingid reason
```

`Meeting`:

```
ID, description
```

`cm_delay_reasons`:

```
ID, reasoncode, reasondescription
```

The tuples returned need to match the following criteria:

- The `MeetingID` in `Event` needs to map to an `ID` in `Meeting`.
- The `reason` value in `Event` can not be null
- The `reason` value in `Event` *can* map to a `reasoncode` in `cm_delay_reasons`.

  - The `reason` value can also not map, but must not be null.
  - If it isn't null, then don't display a reason description.

The reason is for the latter part is simple. `Event.Reason` can either be a code, indicating it matches one of our preconfigured delays for an event. It can also be plaintext, indicating that the user decided their own reason for a delay. The aim is to get both of these, and for those values that do not map, leave the reason description empty.

The SQL query I have come up with is:

```
select 
    m.description, e.startdate, e.offtime, e.reason, d.reasondescription 
from 
    event e, meeting m, cm_delay_reasons d 
where 
    e.meetingid = m.id 
    and (d.reasoncode = e.reason);
```

However, ths isn't displaying the custom reasons that a user can put in. Only the predefined ones that exist in the `cm_delay_reasons` table, so I changed my tact and attempted:

```
select 
    m.description, e.startdate, e.offtime, e.reason, d.reasondescription 
from 
    event e, meeting m, cm_delay_reasons d 
where 
    e.meetingid = m.id 
    and (e.reason is not null);
```

However this is causing duplicates. What I need to work out is how to marry the functionality of the two.

Comment: Not sure if I understood completely, but if it's only a problem of duplicates, why not use `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Yeah, I'm a sucky SQL developer. I just learn enough to get me by as I go.. which is a practise that has yielded some problems.

Comment: You need to map to the cm_delay_reasons on something, otherwise how would you now which delays is to which event? Is the ID in cm_delay_reasons a FK to the Event.ID ?

Comment: No it's not. My colleague offered up a solution anyway, so I thought I'd present it here. It's quite simple when you know how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

After my far more experienced colleague saw me in distress, he helped me out, and explained the concept of a left outer join.

```
 SELECT m.description, e.startdate, e.offtime, e.reason, d.reasondescription 
   FROM event e
        JOIN meeting m ON e.meetingid = m.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN cm_delay_reasons d ON e.reason = d.reasoncode
  WHERE e.reason IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY e.startdate;
```

Comment: More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join?rq=1